# How to get homogeneous screen space coordinates in openGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl, qopenglfunctions

I'm studying opengl and I'v got i little 3d scene with some objects. In GLSL vertex shader I multiply vertexes on matixes like this:

```
vertexPos= viewMatrix * worldMatrix * modelMatrix * gl_Vertex;
gl_Position = vertexPos;
```

vertexPos is a vec4 varying variable and I pass it to fragment shader.
Here is how the scene renders normaly:
[normal render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fp9E.jpg)

But then I wana do a debug render. I write in fragment shader:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(vertexPos.x, vertexPos.x, vertexPos.x, 1.0);
```

vertexPos is multiplied by all matrixes, including perspective matrix, and I assumed that I would get a smooth gradient from the center of the screen to the right edge, because they are mapped in -1 to 1 square. But look like they are in screen space but perspective deformation isn't applied. Here is what I see: 
(dont look at red line and light source, they are using different shader)

[debug render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBh6F.png)

If I devide it by about 15 it will look like this:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(vertexPos.x, vertexPos.x, vertexPos.x, 1.0)/15.0;
```

[devided by 15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEXhm.png)

Can someone please explain me, why the coordinates aren't homogeneous and the scene still renders correctly with perspective distortion? 
P.S. if I try to put gl_Position in fragment shader instead of vertexPos, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A so-called *perspective division* is applied to `gl_Position` after it's computed in a vertex shader:

```
gl_Position.xyz /= gl_Position.w;
```

But it doesn't happen to your varyings unless you do it manually. Thus, you need to add

```
vertexPos.xyz /= vertexPos.w;
```

at the end of your vertex shader. Make sure to do it *after* you copy the value to `gl_Position`, you don't want to do the division twice.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! And what if I'd like to perform a reverse operation? I multiply the coords by inversed matrix, but what to do with W components? I tryied both multiplying and dividing xyz with w but that gave strange results..

Comment: @3dmodels Probably you need to do `pos.xyz *= pos.w;` to cancel out the division first if needed, and then multiply by the inverse matrix.